# Javascript can't apply an existing function to onkeyup

Tags: javascript, iterator, dom-events, html-input, selectors-api

I have a bunch of HTML number inputs, and I have grabbed them by

```
x=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
```

I then try and iterate through this with a for-loop, and apply an `onkeyup` function. The function is this:

```
t=function(elem){


elem.onkeyup=function(e) {
  if(!/[\d\.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
    elem.value='';
}
};
};
```

Basically, what it does is clear the value of the input if there is a letter typed in. I know I can apply it via HTML:

```
<input type='number' onkeyup='t(this)'/>
```

But how can I do it with Javascript? I tried iterating through it with:

```
x=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i].onkeyup=t(this);
}
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I do this?  Please regular JavaScript answers only, no jQuery or other frameworks/libraries.

Comment: Incidentally, this creates a very poor UI experience and users can still enter non–digit characters by copy and paste or drag and drop. Better to check the result when they've finished entering data and advise errors rather than try to out–think the user.

Comment: look into `input` events to replace `keyup`

Answer (score 1):

change

```
x[i].onkeyup=t(this);
```

to

```
x[i].onkeyup=t(x[i]);
```

because `this` isn't what you want it to be

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. Can you make a demo or something? I'm sure I'm missing something small...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, all. I found my answer. Agreeing with Jaromanda X, I needed to change

```
x[i].onkeyup=t(this);
```

to

```
x[i].onkeyup=t(x[i]);
```

This (pun intended ;)was part of the problem, but the main problem was that the valid property name is

```
keyup=function();
```

and not

```
onkeyup=function(){}'
```